# Cumulative probability of Chi-squared distribution

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

> If $X$ is distributed $\frac{\chi_{10}^2}{10}$ , find the  probability that $X > 1.83$

The formula for the Chi-squared CDF I'm using is the following, which is the integral of the PDF formula:

$$P(X\le x)=\int_0^x \frac{x^{(k/2-1)} e^{-x/2}}{2^{k/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}dx$$

$$P(X\gt x)=1-P(X\le x)$$

Where $k$ is the degrees of freedom and $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$

I did reach the correct solution of $P=0.05$ but I don't understand the logic behind it. My main issue is that I know that to find $P(X\gt 1.83)$, the upper limit of integration should be 18.3 instead of 1.83 because of the coefficient $\frac{1}{10}$ in $X$~$\frac{\chi_{10}^2}{10}$, but I don't understand why the coefficient affects the limits of integration as opposed to the integrand itself. To put it symbolically, why is the solution:

$$P(X\gt 1.83)=1-\int_0^{\color{red}{18.3}} \frac{x^{(k/2-1)} e^{-x/2}}{2^{k/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}dx$$

As opposed to:

$$P(X\gt 1.83)=1-\int_0^{1.83} \color{red}{\frac{1}{10}}\frac{x^{(k/2-1)} e^{-x/2}}{2^{k/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}dx$$

I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious here, any clarification is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y\sim \chi_{10}^2$. You can compute $\Pr(\frac{Y}{10}>1.83)$ by at least 2 routes:

**Route 1**:
$$
\Pr\left(\frac{Y}{10}>1.83\right)=\Pr(Y>18.3)=1-F_Y(18.3)=1-\int_0^{18.3}f_Y(s)ds.\tag{I}
$$

**Route 2**: Let $X=\frac{Y}{10}$, then
$$
F_X(x)=\Pr(X<x)=\Pr(Y<10x)=F_Y(10x)\implies f_X(x)=10f_Y(10x).
$$
It follows that $\Pr(\frac{Y}{10}>1.83)=\Pr(X>1.83)$ can be computed as
$$
1-F_X(1.83)=1-\int_0^{1.83}f_X(u)du=1-\int_0^{1.83}\color{blue}{10}f_Y(\color{red}{10}u)du.\tag{II}
$$
So instead of $\color{blue}{10}$, you had $\frac{1}{10}$, and you missed $\color{red}{10}$ altogether. Note that (II) can be obtained from (I) by the substitution: $u=\frac{s}{10}$.